# (Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'always') and (Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'delay')

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Good day guys, I would like to ask what's causing this error?

1. "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method
   'always'"
2. "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'delay'"

These errors are only showing on my Google Chrome Beta(33.0.1750.46 beta-m) and it works well with Firefox Beta(27) and Internet Explorer 11.

I'm using jQuery 1.10.2.

I've just followed the API on using the methods on jQuery's Documentation.

Here are the sample codes:

1. http://goo.gl/0C0UBQ

   ```
   process = $.post(uri, { "input[]": [code, input, apiLangID, postID, type] },
       function(data) {
           // MY CODES HERE
       }, "json")
       .always(function() {
           hide_abort_btn();
           isCompiling = false;
       });
   ```
2. http://goo.gl/JHYvNX

   ```
   var delayDuration = 20000;

   $("#helper-dialog").fadeIn().delay(delayDuration).fadeOut();

   $("#helper-dialog").append("<p><span>" + mes + "</span></p>");
   ```

Comment: `console.log($.fn.jquery)` what does that give you?

Comment: You appear to be using a very old version of jQuery (pre 1.4). Somehow this only appears to apply in your Chrome Beta browser

Comment: Is it possible for a google extension to override a jquery instance included on a web page?

Comment: @KevinB - it shows "1.10.2"

Comment: @Phil - I'm using the latest jQuery

Comment: If you run google chrome in private mode without extensions, does the same thing occur?

Comment: weird but it worked!
It seems its having a conflict with one of my extensions (Tamper Monkey)..
Oh well, I've just removed it and everything seems fine.
Thanks @KevinB!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is with one of my chrome extensions...

First, as suggest by KevinB, I switched to Incognito Mode with extensions disabled.

Next, I debugged it by enabling the extensions one by one until I found the culprit (Tamper Monkey)...

Then, I simply removed it from Chrome and my script now runs fine!